# How to store media files path in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database in mysql with phpmyadmin to store music albums as localhost  and then added some tables to the database, but I really have no idea how to store my mp3 files path in a table with **URL** column for them? I have many directories inside my hard disk but can't figure it out how to handle it.

For example.

> E:\Entertainment Lib\Music Library\Artist Name\Album Name\Song Name.mp3

[Here is my table structure](http://i62.tinypic.com/149upaw.png)

Comment: Add more details, like your tables, columns, etc. Also, what exactly you looking for? To export all the paths where you have stored your music (inside your hard disk) to a specific column into one for your tables?

Comment: What is wrong with varchar ? Are you facing some problems with inserting?

Comment: no! but i only wanted to know how to put file path in url field for example as i mentioned above!

Comment: A URL is just a character string, so you can put your URL in a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to iterate through the folder you wish to index for tracks.. Something like the following will run a recursive check.

We will create a class for the song, just so we can extend it later if needed.

```
class Track {
    public $location;
}
```

Then we will select the folder we want to recursively scan and proceed to do so.

We will use the lovely [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) for this.

```
$result = array();

$musicFolder = "c:\\music\\Folder\\";
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($musicFolder)) as $filename)
{
    //This can be extended to check for other files also.
    //But for your purposes we can stick to mp3!
    if(getExtention($filename) == "mp3" )
    {
        $arrayItem = new Track();
        $arrayItem->location = $filename;
        array_push($result, $arrayItem);
    }
}
```

Right now you have all your file locations inside the array object `$result` . This you can then insert however you like into the MySQL DB.

I think this is what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be define some location where all your directories placed.

For e.g. `/var/www/site/upload`

take that value a config value so you can use at later stage whenever require. Now to store values in database, you should store path starting from your base location.

```
/dir1/file1.mp3
/dir2/file2.mp3
/dir3/file3.mp3
```

This way in future if you have to change location of your upload directory then just move your files to new location and edit your location with new value and you are done.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer!  but can you give me an example how to define my all directories with a more detailed example.